# dependant selectboxes

Tags: php, javascript, html

Whats the best way to have dependant select boxes e.g.

selectbox1 = choose value 
selectbox2 = values based on selectbox1

when a user selects selectbox2 create a ordered list.

when finish selecting post ordered list to next page.

i can't work out how to do this.

any guidance would be great.

Comment: Have you tried searching for similar questions on here? This question is asked almost every day.

Comment: Try this - http://bit.ly/A3FdjP

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

I ended up hiding another multi selectbox with java and populating it with the li to post the data to the next page.

i couldn't find examples on this...